# How to rerender a React component which gets API data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React and JavaScript and I am trying to make a simple React web page which fetches from data from an API and displays it. However, I would like the React component which renders the data to automatically refresh itself every 60 seconds or so, and for there to be a button which the user can manually refresh the page as well.

I have attempted to make an auto-refresh system using `setInterval` inside of `componentDidMount` but that approach didn't seem to work. This is the code which I have for the component that renders the data:

```
class Player extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    karma: 0,
    username: "",
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=INSERTAPIKEYHERE&name=${this.props.username}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (!data.player) {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        karma: "There is no data for that player!",
        username: "There is no data for that player!",
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        karma: ", Karma: " + data.player.karma,
        username: "Username: " + data.player.displayname,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <p>
            {this.state.username}
            {this.state.karma}
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, the data is fetched in `componentDidMount`, it is assigned to the `karma` and `username` keys in `state` and then it is rendered.

And this is the code for my `App.js`:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="playerPage">
          <Player username="SirArchibald97" />
        </div>
        <button>Refresh</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I create a new `Player` component as well as a button to refresh the data.

Comment: this is your full code or is just the render part ?

Comment: Are you going to make another API request when the button is clicked to refresh?

Comment: @dna this is the full code

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine I am hoping to get it so it makes the exact same request when you refresh it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this (i didn't test my code)

```
class Player extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    karma: 0,
    username: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      setInterval(loadData, 60 * 1000);
  }

  async loadData() {
    const url = `https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=INSERTAPIKEYHERE&name=${this.props.username}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (!data.player) {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        karma: "There is no data for that player!",
        username: "There is no data for that player!",
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        karma: ", Karma: " + data.player.karma,
        username: "Username: " + data.player.displayname,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <p>
            {this.state.username}
            {this.state.karma}
          </p>
        )}
       <button onClick={loadData}>Refresh</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```